# How implement trinomial expansion without nested loops.

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm in process of writing program for equation simplifications. In this program in want to use binomial and trinomial theorems.

With binomial expansion:

*(x+y)^r*

*Sum(k -> r) x^[r-k] y^[k]*,

where k is 0 and r is degree of binomial.

I can do it like this:

```
  for (k=0; k<=r; k++) {
      x_degree=r-k;
      y_degree=k;  
  }
```

Otherwise, if i want to implement trinomial theoreme i should satisfy constraints of form:

*(a+b+c)^n*

*Sum(n choose i, j, k) a^i b^j c^k,*

where n is degree of trinomial and i+j+k=n.

I think about it for a while, but i can't figure out something better than loop through all possible combinations, as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<=n; j++)
        for (int k=0; k<=n; k++) {
            if((i+j+k)==n) {
                find_coefficient(i,j,k);
                set_degree_values(i,j,k);
                proceed();
            } 
        }
```

So my questions is: **how implement trinomial expansion without looping through all possible combinations of degrees?**

Thank you.

Comment: you can use two loops instead of 3 as you did for binomial using 1 loop instead of 2.

Comment: what exactly is you want. I can't understand your question properly.

Comment: In your binomial example, you are missing the code that actually does any power raising and multiplying.

Comment: Your stated objective is to perform an expansion of the trinomial.  The result has a term for each distinct combination of degrees.  It's hard to see how you could achieve your objective without looping through all the degree combinations you need to include in the expansion.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! Thank you sasha, this is a great suggestion! With 3 loops, (if i not mistaken) complexity of this procedure is O(n^3), i just thought there should be some "clever" way to reduce it to O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the fourth degree as an example, the powers of the three variables can be listed as

```
004, 013, 022, 031, 040, 
103, 112, 121, 130, 
202, 211, 220,
301, 310, 
400
```

The logics is to decrement the rightmost digit and increment the one to its left. When the latter reaches `r`, you increment the one to its left and reset the right digits (that's a modified carry operation).

This scheme can be implemented by means of `n` counters and generalizes to the multinomial theorem. I wouldn't be surprised that the coefficients can be computed incrementally as well. (Actually, the counters will simulate nested loops.)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Daouts! This is a cool method. I will try to implement it in form of multinomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove one loop very simply as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<=n-i; j++) {   // Note change to upper limit
        int k = n - i - j;         // Calculate k rather than loop
        find_coefficient(i,j,k);
        set_degree_values(i,j,k);
        proceed(); 
        }
```